# Elle entend le cri des enfants

Tags: articles

I read this sentence in my French studies book. Why is "cri" in singular? Several children surely cry in plural? Shouldn't it be "Elle entend *les cris* des enfants"? Or is this a gray zone and either way is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about the simple fact of children crying, that is screaming, as in the sentence "Elle entend … des enfants.", you say usually "les cris des enfants", "les cris de l'enfant" (if there is just one child) ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+cris+des+enfants%2Cle+cri+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20cris%20des%20enfants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20cri%20des%20enfants%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cles%20cris%20des%20enfants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20cri%20des%20enfants%3B%2Cc0)). Nevertheless, in this sentence "cri" can also have other meanings, depending on the context.

The word "cri" has two meanings that are very close to one another and if the writer, not conscious of that or careless, does not take care of ensuring the existence of a proper context  there can be ambiguity in his/her text.

*The meanings can be extracted from the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cri).*

> A.− Son(s) généralement bref(s) et aigu(s), émis instinctivement par les cordes vocales sous l'effet de certaines émotions.
>
> 1. Expression phonique d'une sensation, d'un état physique ou moral, ressenti en profondeur très intensément.
> 2. Son de voix caractérisant un animé et, p. ext., une situation, un événement.

In "1." the word is taken as meaning an occurrence (*expression phonique*) of the particular sound called "cri";  in "2." the word is taken as the sound, not in individual instances of hearing it, but as a sort of sound particular to a creature (*caractérisant un animé*).

In the sentence "Elle entend … enfants.", since "enfants" is in the plural the meaning of "cri", out of the two, must be that in "2.", that is "type of sound" (here produced by children).

*Here are examples for the case "sound".*

([ref., 1910](https://books.google.fr/books?id=q4EvAAAAIAAJ&q=%22le+cri+des+enfants%22&dq=%22le+cri+des+enfants%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB6bCbur7sAhVLz4UKHZthCmIQ6AEwBXoECAoQAg)) Au point de vue du diagnostic et de la symptomatologie, M. Sisto insiste sur un signe nouveau qu'il a le premier signalé à Buenos Aires avec le Dr Gaing, à savoir le cri des enfants hérédo-syphilitiques. Ce cri, incessant, de jour et de nuit, ...

([ref., 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CzYxaFZT6rkC&pg=PT6&dq=%22le+cri+des+enfants%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB6bCbur7sAhVLz4UKHZthCmIQ6AEwCnoECCgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22le%20cri%20des%20enfants%22&f=false))  Des milliers de tentes, maintenant, se tenaient serrées le long des remparts, dessinant d'immenses faubourgs de tissu multicolores où se mêlaient le cri des enfants qui jouaient dans le sable et les braiements du bétail.

([ref., 1997](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xK2ZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT98&dq=%22le+cri+des+enfants%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB6bCbur7sAhVLz4UKHZthCmIQ6AEwB3oECCQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22le%20cri%20des%20enfants%22&f=false)) Qui n'a jamais regretté, en se promenant dans un centre-ville restauré, de ne plus y entendre le cri des enfants qui jouent, chassés avec leurs parents par des loyers prohibitifs ? Les modes de vie à venir inciteront à relancer la construction ...

*Examples for the case "occurrence"*

- Le cri d'un enfant la réveilla mais ne fut pas répété et elle se rendormit aussitôt.
- Les cris de ses enfants l'irritaient maintenant et elle ferma la fenêtre.

Another possible explanation is given by the figurative meaning of the word "cri", that is when "cri" means something as in "cri du cœur" (cry of the heart);  there is hardly any context possible for a plural if that is the meaning to be given to "cri" in "Elle entend…"; the almost unique context is that of children (rather mature children) who are having a collective concern or problem.

*Example*

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=neXZOOpIaiYC&pg=PT198&dq=%22le+cri+des+enfants%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB6bCbur7sAhVLz4UKHZthCmIQ6AEwC3oECC4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22le%20cri%20des%20enfants%22&f=false)) Et Dieu aujourd'hui, c'est le cri des enfants irakiens.

---

*Answer to comments from **[user Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/elle-entend-le-cri-des-enfants/43307?noredirect=1#comment111447_43307)***

I am aware of this use of the singular in lieu of a plural ("le ronronnement de ses deux chats qui dormaient près d'elles, l'aboiement des chiens au dehors était à peine perceptible, le bourdonnement des abeilles volant de fleur en fleur", …). In spite of this evidence, I fail to sense that that this is the principle to be contended with in this case. I can't say I have a solid argument, but several facts seem to point to the second definition.

Without contestation, "1" denotes an occurrence , but if "2" refers to the nature of a sound, it does so as denoting "a sound the nature of which is typical of X"; it is nevertheless a term that you can use for an occurrence.

For instance, "il entendit le cri de la chouette" does mean that some sound was heard, and this sound was characterized as that of an owl, but not an occurrence of an owl hooting (although in most cases that is the conclusion): it could have been an imitation by a human being (as a signal for instance). Of course,  "la chouette" has to be taken as a generic term, whereas in the OP's sentence "des enfants" is not perhaps to be construed as the generic "les enfants" but as a determinative.

I tend to believe that it is not so obvious that "son caractéristique de" is not the idea. First if the singular is used so as to signify a plural, the following ngrams show that with the main verb, "entendre" (it occasions many occurrences of several constructions), the singular is not found.

[entendre les cris des enfants,<s>entendre le cri des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendre+les+cris+des+enfants%2Centendre+le+cri+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[entend les cris des enfants,<s>entend le cri des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entend+les+cris+des+enfants%2Centend+le+cri+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[entendait les cris des enfants,<s>entendait le cri des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendait+le+cri+des+enfants%2Centendait+les+cris+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[entendu les cris des enfants,<s>entendu le cri des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendu+le+cri+des+enfants%2Centendu+les+cris+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[entendant les cris des enfants,<s>entendant le cri des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendant+le+cri+des+enfants%2Centendant+les+cris+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

In the case of "rire" the singular is not found a whole lot.

[entendait les rires des enfants,<s>entendait le rire des enfants</s>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendait+le+rire+des+enfants%2Centendait+les+rires+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[entendre les rires des enfants,entendre le rire des enfants](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendre+le+rire+des+enfants%2Centendre+les+rires+des+enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

However, an examination of "le rire des enfants" in Google Books shows that "des enfants" can be generic or not, but "rire" seems to mean "suite de sons caractérisant un individu" (I think the definition is missing in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rire))

In a large number of cases at least, the natural interpretation seems to be that of "rire caractéristique de".

ex. 1 :  Je me demande où pouvait bien se trouver le tableau noir et ferme les yeux pour essayer d'entendre le rire des enfants. (*Not a particular instance of laughter, but laughter as the children are (were) used to be given to; "des enfants" is determinative.*)

ex. 2 : Je veux de nouveau entendre le rire des enfants ! Je veux que vous recommenciez à fleurir les tombes de vos disparus . Rallumez les braises qui dorment en vous pour que vos prières fassent trembler le ciel ! (*Not a particular instance of laughter, but laughter as children are used to be given to; "des enfants" is generic.*)

How come this replacement by the singular is so common for other terms (to the point of being the unique form in some cases), but not for "cri"? Why is not the otherwise generalized principle applied?

[entendait les aboiements des chiens,entendait l'aboiement des chiens](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendait+les+aboiements+des+chiens%2Centendait+l%27aboiement+des+chiens&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[<s>entendre les bourdonnements des abeilles</s>,entendre le bourdonnement des abeilles](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendre+les+bourdonnements+des+abeilles%2Centendre+le+bourdonnement+des+abeilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[<s>entend les bourdonnements des abeilles</s>,entend le bourdonnement des abeilles](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entend+les+bourdonnements+des+abeilles%2Centend+le+bourdonnement+des+abeilles%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[<s>entendait les bourdonnements des abeilles</s>,entendait le bourdonnement des abeilles](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendait+les+bourdonnements+des+abeilles%2Centendait+le+bourdonnement+des+abeilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[<s>entendre les bruits des pas</s>,entendre le bruit des pas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendre+le+bruit+des+pas%2Centendre+les+bruits+des+pas&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

[<s>entendre les sifflements des balles</s>,entendre le sifflement des balles](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entendre+le+sifflement+des+balles%2Centendre+les+sifflements+des+balles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: wow, what an answer!

Comment: I disagree with your interpreation. Defintion 1 refers to an occurence (le cri que je viens d'entendre) whereas definition 2 refers to the nature of sound (le cri des oiseaux). Here it's very obviouly not used as in definition 2. Even if it's screams emanating from multiple children, French grammar allows to refer to it as if it were a single (general or collective) scream. And it's definitely still an occurence as in definition 1. "Elle entend le cri des enfants" isn't about how they scream, but about the fact they do.

Comment: (iterpretation/nature of the sound/obviously/occurrence. Sorry, I wish I could fix the typos.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I made an addition to my post; a lot of interesting things could thus be added.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I didn't have the possibility of a background sound in mind. My remark was mainly that you can't deduce definition 2 from the use of singular.

Answer (score 4):

Both can work depending on the context, take an English analogy like "I see the agony of these people", surely there is more than one in that situation.

In this, it depends on the context too, if she is in a place and hears kids screaming nearby, so she is hearing a scream aka *le cri*, but if these kids are being mistreated so she is hearing their screams translated to *les cris*. Usually *les cris* is used when someone is distressed and shouting for help.

---

(Traduction libre :)
Les deux fonctionnent selon le contexte. Si elle est dans un endroit où il y a plusieurs enfants qui crient elle peut n'entendre qu'un seul cri, donc *le cri*, mais si ces enfants sont maltraités elle entend leurs cris et elle écrit *les cris*.

Answer (score 2):

> **Edit:** See Stéphane's comment for a more nuanced understanding than the one I've proposed here.

> **Révision:** Voir le commentaire de Stéphane pour une explication plus nuancée que celle que je propose ici.

---

*[English original]*

Generally, if each person has only one, French uses the singular.

The language is happy to distribute the noun to all the people in question, like the multiplication of the <strike>loaves</strike> loaf.

Case in point: There's a line in *La peste* where he's talking about a crowd and says something like:

> La crainte se fit voir sur leur front.

"What?" you say. "How can the whole crowd have one forehead?" So you take the liberty of rewriting it:

> La crainte se fit voir sur leurs fronts.

"What?" says a Francophone. "How can people have multiple foreheads?"

So you leave it as it is and forge on a little bit wiser...

---

*[Traduction libre :) de la main de None]*

En général, chacun ayant un seul objet possédé le français utilise le singulier. La langue se satisfait de distribuer l'objet à chacun comme la multiplication des pains  <strike>du pain</strike>.

Exemple concret : dans *La peste* il y a un endroit où l'auteur parle de plusieurs personnes et il écrit quelque chose comme :

> La crainte se fit voir sur leur front.

« Hein ? » me direz-vous en tant qu'anglophone, « comment plusieurs personnes peuvent-elles avoir un seul front ? On réécrit la phrase :

> La crainte se fit voir sur leurs fronts.

« Hein ? » dit un francophone « comment des gens peuvent-ils avoir plusieurs fronts ? ».

On finit par laisser tel quel et on poursuit sa route avec un grain de sagesse en plus.

Comment: The only occurrence of "leur front" in "*La Peste" is in the sentence "En
entrant, Cottard et Rambert essuyèrent leur front.". However, there is a case where "crainte" is found and the word "moral" answers to your explanation. (1:2)

Comment: "Mais ce qu'il peut dire, c'est que l'existence de ces camps,
l'odeur d'hommes qui en venait, les énormes voix des haut-parleurs
dans le crépuscule, le mystère des murs et la crainte de ces lieux réprouvés, pesaient lourdement sur **le moral** de nos concitoyens et ajoutaient encore au désarroi et au malaise de tous." Camus, *La Peste* (2/2)

Comment: @LPH Good finds, thanks. All of the above serve to illustrate the rule in any case.

Comment: What about the fact the OP says this is cries?

Comment: @Lambie Right — we have to assume the author meant that either they gave a collective cry, or they each gave one cry, but *les cris* would be unlikely unless they each gave multiple cries. Is that how you read it, too?

Comment: Yes, I do, except that is can be cries or screams. I have no issue with the singular and agree completely with you.

Comment: I'm sorry but your understanding of the plural is a bit wrong. You can't say “il y avait des couleurs sur leur t-shirt” unless you consider they wear it as a uniform and they are precisely similar. On the other hand, “il y avait des couleurs sur leurs t-shirts" is perfectly normal and it doesn't mean each of them wears multiple items. The use of singular or plural is often just a nuance. The singular conveys generality in some way.

Comment: (it="this kind of t-shirt", they="the t-shirts" in case the switch from one language to the other was confusing)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez That's very interesting. Thank you for adding more nuance to my understanding. To confirm, then, the reason 'front' is singular is because each person's forehead is functionally identical? And by the same token, since it would be hard to say whether two "cries" were identical or not, the singular/plural could be a matter of interpretation or in free variation?

Comment: Yup. You've nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that *crier* is a partial false friend and only means "to shout/to scream", not "to weep".

Singular is possible here and means either a synchronized scream or a generic scream, the idea being no individual screams are referred to.

> She hears the children's scream/shout.

Luke also rightly says if each child only shout once, the singular is common.

Without context, it is hard to tell what happened, but say if all kids are watching a show/movie and a monster suddenly appears, they will all emit a loud cry at the same time. That would be a case where the singular is better.

Comment: It depends because we also have: She could hear the cries of the children. There isn't enough context to tell whether this is happy cries or screams of fear.

Comment: @Lambie Granted, I only knew *to cry* being used for *pleurer*.